# Making Carousel Slide or Fade in Twitter Bootstrap with IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have made Carousel in Twitter Bootstrap and it's working fine (sliding) in all the browsers except IE. Now, I am really trying hard to make it work in IE, if not slide then at least it may fade-in / fade-out.

This is what I did:

```js
$('#myCarouselforsolutions').carousel({
  interval: 3000
});

var slideFrom;
var slideTo;
$('#myCarouselforsolutions').on('slide', function(e) {
  slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
  slideTo = $(e.relatedTarget).index();


  if (typeof slideTo == "undefined") {
    slideTo = 2;
  }
  //console.log ("slide To " + slideTo + " and From " + slideFrom);
  $('.media-module').removeClass('primary-one-background')
    .removeClass('primary-two-background')
    .removeClass('primary-three-background')
    .removeClass('primary-four-background')
    .removeClass('primary-five-background')
    .addClass($(solution_list[slideTo]).attr('value'));
});



$("#prev-solution, #next-solution").click(function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="module colored home-solutions primary-two-background">


  <div id="myCarouselforsolutions" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner carousel-inner-at-home">


      <div class="content-container">

        <h1 id="num-solutions"></h1>
        <h2>SOLUTIONS</h2>
        <div id="swipe-container-home-solutions">

          <div class="item active" id="solutions-slide-dimensions">

            <div class="solution-preview" value="primary-two-background">
              <a href="/Index/solutions/periscope/">
                <h2>Periscope</h2>
              </a>
              <p>
                Improves return on sales through better pricing, promotions, assortment, and performance management</p>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="item" id="solutions-slide-dimensions">

            <div class="solution-preview" value="primary-five-background">
              <a href="/Index/solutions/objective-health/">
                <h2>Objective Health</h2>
              </a>
              <p>Supports community hospitals and small regional systems to improve their cost performance and strategy</p>
            </div>

          </div>



        </div>

      </div>



    </div>
    <a class="arrow arrow-left hidden-phone" href="#myCarouselforsolutions" data-slide="prev"></a>
    <a class="arrow arrow-right hidden-phone" href="#myCarouselforsolutions" data-slide="next"></a>
  </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I also was looking for a solution, this one helped me even on Bootstrap 3:
https://github.com/tybruffy/ie-bootstrap-carousel - download **ie-bootstrap-carousel.min.js** here, then include it AFTER the bootstrap.min.js:

```
<body>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<!-- /Bootstrap -->
...    
<!--[if lte IE 9]>       
    <script src="ie/ie-bootstrap-carousel.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
...
```

Comment: Update - works better with my edits - https://github.com/logvynenko/ie-bootstrap-carousel/commit/2bc19ce38cfe12487290f27a1a1afa39218f699e

Answer (score 1):

Oleksandr Logvynenko's solution is definitely a good start but the link he gave, doesnt work on ie9, ie8
You can use this JS instead (thanks to Barry vd. Heuvel)
https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/6155151

Answer (score 0):

There's a fix for this on gitHub, the pull request was denied but it works great: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/3052/files